# Why is the adverb "often" treated differently?

Tags: grammar, usage, adverbs

In many dictionaries, such as Merriam-Webster, the adverb "often" is defined as follows:

> **often** (adverb): *many times*

However, this adverb can be used in some ways different from the other adverbs of frequency such as *frequently*, *sometimes*, and *rarely*. For example,

> How *often* do you call your mother?
>
> He travels more *often* than I do.
>
> He calls home that *often*.

I know the meaning of the adverb in such examples; however, I wonder why the other adverbs of frequency cannot be used in such ways. Is there any specific grammatical point here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adverbs *frequently* and *rarely* fit easily into any of your example sentences, at least to my ear. The word *sometimes* doesn't fit, but that is because it doesn't make sense semantically.

You can use *more*, *less*, *very* or *extremely* with any of *frequently*, *rarely*, and *often*, but you can't say "more sometimes".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, can we say "how rarely do you call your mother?" and "he calls home that rarely"? I have never seen such examples.

Comment: Idiomatically, we habitually ask, for example, ***How often does that happen**?* as a rhetorical question (perhaps written with ***!*** rather than ***?***). Regardless of whether the "expected" answer is ***frequently / all the time*** OR ***rarely / never.***

Comment: @Later While not common, "that rarely.." is quite possible, given the right context. "He called home after three years, and talked to his mother."... "He calls home that rarely?"

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty How about "how rarely do you call your mother?"?

Comment: @Later It would be unusual, as a question, unless a context with "rare" is established. But if someone says "I rarely call my mother.",  "How rarely?" is quite natural.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes. However, the adverb "often" can be used in such cases without a given context while other frequency adverbs like "rarely" need an already established context, right?  Now, the question is: why is the adverb "often" treated in such a different way?

Comment: @Later I don't think it's treated differently. It's just a different word, and falls into different customary uses.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think your last comment actually answers the OP, so I accept this answer.